# How can I scroll to to the top of a "simple" react-list when it's redisplayed?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using [react-list](https://github.com/orgsync/react-list) to display lists data within Material-UI [Tab](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs) components.

I'm using the `simple` `type` in the list, e.g.

```
<ReactList itemRenderer={::this.renderItem}
           length={this.props.contacts.length}
           pageSize={20}
           type="simple"
           useTranslate3d={true} />
```

I have to use `simple` as I don't know the size of the rendered items.

This means I can't use `scrollTo` fully. From the docs

> Note that if you aren't using type='uniform' or an itemSizeGetter, you will only be able to scroll to an element that has already been rendered.

When I'm work with the list on one tab and scrolled, say, half way down, when I switch to another tab, I'm scrolled some way down the list that has been updated with the new data.

What I'd like is to have the react-list reset to display the first item when I switch tabs.

I've tried putting a `ref` in `ReactList` component and then calling `scrollTo`---like this

```
ref={c => this.list = c}

componentDidUpdate() {
    this.list.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Had no effect.

Comment: Couldn't you use window.scrollTo()? I think that should work even without rendered items?

Comment: Added to the question. Tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: No you misunderstood me. I didn't mean for you to try and use refs, or component. My point was actually trying to use the window. Is this not an option for you? window.scrollTo(0, 0);

Comment: Oh. Where would I call that? There's an AppBar component above the list, so I have to scroll the component rather than the page, I think.

Comment: would scrolling to the AppBar help you? If it would I might have a solution for you.

Comment: The AppBar is fixed. I need the react-list, under the AppBar, to display the first item at the top of its viewpoint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129262/discussion-between-usedtobefat-and-dommer).

Comment: When you say switch to another tab, do you mean a tab in your app or a browser tab? Either way you would need to scroll when the tab is focused, not on componentDidUpdate wouldn't you?